# Html2canvas and resolution

Tags: dpi, html2canvas

I would like to render a div as a picture that would be printed in 12cm x 8 cm.
What should be the actual div size to do so considering that:

- I need the best definition possible and miss no details
- the div will mix web fonts, divs and high res pictures of various DPI.

Converting pixels to centimeters is trivial until de DPI comes into play.

I used a 1417x945 pixels div as I read that it’s about 12x8cm but when I go to the printer shop, it happens that the picture actual size exceeds 40cm in length.
And I have a hard time believing that reducing my div by about a factor of 4 would generate a well defined print.
So I’m confused as I don’t know if I need to divide the size of the div or keep the details and specify the DPI output I need with HTML2canvas (which makes more sense to me).

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you even rasterize your page? Convert it to a pdf instead if you want to print it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you tell me more about that? How would it help? And the question remains even for PDF's, doesn't it? I mean, what size of div do I need to consider as an input to print a 12x8cm document at its best?
If I'm having it wrong, don't hesitate to tell me why. Thanks.

Comment: Once converted to pdf, all your texts and fonts and borders etc. will remain as vectors. So there is no dpi needed. The printer will be able to use its own max dpi to render it on paper. You would have to set in the printer's config at which scale you want it to be printed, that's about it.

Comment: Thank you very much but I'm still not getting it. I mean, how do I determine then my div size for an optimal print at 12x8?
I totally get the fact that you say it doesn't matter but then between a div of "1417x945" or a div of "141.7x94,5" or a div of "14170x9450" containing pictures of the same size, one is the better than the others if I want a 12x8cm picture at the end.
So,  I know you are certainly right but I'm missing something then.
Did you get that I have full sized pictures too in these div, not only text and borders?
Vectors for text and borders, I get that, but not for pictures.

Comment: You can set your page's css only for printing devices, you can also set length values to the `cm`, `in`or `pt` units. Generally, when exporting to pdf from your browser's printing interface, it will convert all it can to vector data, and all rasters to the best quality. Now to convert to the best size, you would have to know what dpi the printer is set to. You didn't mention that. Usually, for professional printers, we can assume 300dpi. If we do a direct conversion ppi to dpi, then a 12*8cm raster should be at least ~1420x940px (300 * 4.7in)x(300 * 3.14in).

Comment: Which gets us back to square one. My div is 1417px x 945px (about the size you mentioned which is supposed to be 12cmx8cm in 300 DPI) and when I go to the printer shop, which printers are set to 300 DPI indeed, he says the pictures are 50cmx33cm and he has to correct that manually via a software (my Photoshop agrees). Which means there is something in the pictures that forces the machines/software to consider that the pictures are set to 72 DPI.
What I would like is to get an output from html2canvas that would directly be considered to be 12x8 cm in 300 DPI.

Comment: ... html2canvas returns a canvas. A canvas is dpi ignorant. If you do export it to a raster image (either png or jpg) the dpi information of the image will not be set in the file. Most softwares agree on the point that an image file without dpi information will default to 72dpi. If you do export it to jpeg (not recommended for texts), then you could add density_X and density_Y EXIF metadatas, and for png there is a [*pixels per meter*](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/book/chapter11.html#png.ch11.div.8) metadata that you can set too. But you would have to do it manually...

Comment: Ok, thanks, it starts to make sense! At least you confirmed the Div size which is the one I use. Now it's all about meta-data.